# Handling Test and Dev Mnesia databases in Elixir

Tags: elixir, mnesia

I'm learning Elixir and need some help. I have a simple app that uses `mnesia` (not `Amnesia` for now). When I start `mnesia` I do:

```
:mnesia.create_schema([node()])
:mnesia.create_table(Table, [attributes: [:id, :name]])
:mnesia.start
```

This creates a `Mnesia.nonode@nohost` directory. What I want is to have at least 2 different databases, one for tests and one for development. I'm currently checking this using `Mix.env`. I plan to erase the test database every time my application stops and create it every time it starts (using the `start` and `stop` methods).

The data directory created by `mnesia` takes the name of the Erlang VM, that is why I guess I need to name my VMs according to the environment (`:dev`, `:test` or `:prod`).

Is this possible? Is this the right way ?

---

**Update**

I know I can choose where the data of my mnesia database is stored (thank you Maryna). But when I specify a "custom" directory, I have this strange behaviour:

```
iex(1)> :mnesia.system_info()
===> System info in version {mnesia_not_loaded,nonode@nohost,
                                {1486,66262,472243}}, debug level =  trace <===
opt_disc. Directory     <<"/my/custom/dir">> is NOT used.
use fallback at restart = false
running db nodes   = []
stopped db nodes   = [nonode@nohost] 
:no
```

So I can see that it knows where I want to store my data, however it's telling me "is NOT used". I don't know why ... Then

```
iex(2)> :mnesia.create_schema([node()])
{:error, {:EXIT, :function_clause}}
```

It fails creating the schema (works fine when I dont specify a "custom" directory). Any ideas?

---

**Update 2**

MUST use single quotes around the directory path (no idea why)

Comment: you can access databa by defining dir http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21150613/is-there-a-built-in-mechanism-for-us-to-launch-mnesia-in-elixir. line iex(2)> :application.set_env(:mnesia, :dir, 'sample')

Comment: Thank you Maryna for your input, it helped but still encounter issues ...

Comment: I see update, probably, it waits atom

Answer (score 6):

The easiest way to have separate `mnesia` databases for different environments is to specify the `Mix.env` in your application configuration. You can put something like this in your `config.exs`:

```
config :mnesia, dir: 'mnesia/#{Mix.env}/#{node()}'
```

---

**But there are a few important things you need to take care of:**

- Use have to use single quotes instead of double quotes
- The parent directory for the database **must exist**, otherwise it'll fail. *(The reason it doesn't fail when you don't specify a custom path is because your app directory already exists)*